# Replace items in the string for the exception of the last occurance

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I have the following code which grabs a the categories from my wordpress blog and replaces all the line breaks with a pipe.

```
<?php $variable = wp_list_categories('style=none&echo=0'); ?>
<?php $variable = str_replace('<br />', ' | ', $variable); ?>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

The code works - however I need the last occurrence to be ignored.
Any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste sample HTML you are getting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rtrim()`. It will remove the last `|` from the string.

```
echo rtrim($variable, '|');
```

**Update**

```
$str = "hhh|yyy|YY|ll";
$last = strrpos($str, '|');
$part = rtrim(substr($str, 0, $last), '|');
if($last < strlen($str))
    $part .= substr($str, $last + 1), (strlen($str) -$last));

echo $part;
```

Comment: this won't cover all bases, what if the last occurence of `<br />` is in the middle of some tags or text, this will only work if the last `<br />` is literaly the last part of the string, html strings can be complex

Comment: @Ghost for that case it would not work. Have to do some tricks then.

Comment: @sgtBOSE - I've just tried rtrim but didnt make any difference :-/



<?php $variable = wp_list_categories('style=none&echo=0'); ?>
<?php $variable = str_replace('<br />', ' | ', $variable); ?>
<?php echo rtrim($variable, ' | '); ?>

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to get the last pipe `|` character with `strrpos`, once found, just remove it using the string index, then use a `substr_replace` and replace it with a `<br/>` again:

```
$variable = str_replace(array('<br/>', '<br />', '<br>'), '|', $variable);
$last_pipe = strrpos($variable, '|');
if($last_pipe !== false) {
    $variable[$last_pipe] = ''; // remove
    $variable = substr_replace($variable, '<br/>', $last_pipe, 0); // replace
}
echo $variable;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/58wjni)

Sidenote: This would be the dirty solution to it, but if you have more complex operations to be done, it might be better to just use HTML Parsers with this one, `DOMDocument` in particular in conjunction with `->replaceChild` with regression.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($variable, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$br_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('br');
$i = $br_tags->length - 2; // -2 to leave the last one conversion
while($i > -1) {
    $br = $br_tags->item($i);
    $pipe = $dom->createTextNode('|');
    $br->parentNode->replaceChild($pipe, $br);
    $i--;
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RuRWYR)

Answer (score 0):

When using `str_replace` with category variable it return categories `|` pipe seprated with space before category name

so you can remove last two characters one with `space` and second is `|` pipe.

```
$variable = wp_list_categories('style=none&echo=0'); 
$variable = str_replace('<br />', '|', $variable);
var_dump($variable);
echo substr($variable,0,strlen($variable)-2);
```

if you use Pipe with spaces before and after the category name then use `-4` instead `-2`